# Is it possible to make a link that functions as same as form does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I have 2 forms that submit a comment.

**Form Type A**

```
<%=form_for(([@community, @comment]), :remote => true, :class => 'form' ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, :id => "body", :class => "chat" %> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
<% end %>
```

**Form Type B**

```
<%=form_for(([@user, @comment]), :remote => true, :class => 'form' ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, :id => "body", :class => "chat" %> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
<% end %>
```

Now, I want to have **link_to** button that functions as same as those forms do if a user clicks it.

When the user click on the link, `@comment` will be automatically filled just like below.
From **Form Type A**
`@comment = "this is for community"`
From **Form Type B**
`@comment = "this is for user"`

How can I do that? As far as I understand my situation.
Form is `put` type, then **link_to** is `get` type so it's impossible to re-use transaction of form.

Comment: Can you use the `onclick` event of the link and invoke the form submission?

Comment: @abiessu Thanks for a comment. Is it usual to use onclick event?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "*transaction of form*" but if you're asking if you can create/modify data via a single button or link than the answer is **Yes**, it is possible.

1. You can actually `put` with a `link_to` in rails (`{:method => :put}` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)
2. If you want a button to do this you should checkout `button_to` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

It's better to use `button_to`.

Comment: Thanks! But how can you pass `params[:comment][:body]`and all others?

Comment: Look into `button_to`. Another option could be to create a from and give it an id. Then use the `form: "form_id"` to associate various input fields with that form. In this case it would be the `button_to`'s form.